# A question on the closure of a set

Tags: general-topology

I do not know how to prove the following. However, it seems to be true when I set A=rational numbers and B=irrationals. Any hint will be helpful. $\overline{A}\setminus\overline{B}\subseteq\overline{A\setminus B}$, where the bar on top denotes closure.

Comment: You can prove it directly from the definitions. What does it mean for a point to be in the closure of a set. Hence what does it mean for a point to be in $\overline{A}\setminus \overline{B}$?

Comment: @user45765 Since you write the you have figured it out, you could post an answer with your solution. (The question will not remain unanswered and other users can give you some useful comments about your solution.)

Comment: I posted my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Let $x\in \overline A -\overline B$. Then $x\in \overline A$ and $x\not\in \overline B$. So there is an neighbourhood $U_{1}$ of x and any neighbourhood U of x, $U\cap A\not=\emptyset$ and $U_{1}\cap B=\emptyset$ as B is a subset of closure of B. Consider $U_{1}\cap U$ which is open and nonempty as x is in and it is intersection of two open sets. Then $U_{1}\cap U\cap A\not=\emptyset$ and $U\cap U_{1}\cap B=\emptyset$ Hence $U\cap U_{1}\cap B^{c}=U\cap U_{1}$. So $U\cap U_{1}\cap A\cap B^{c}$ is non empty. Since U is arbitrary, so we have x in the closure of $A-B$.

Comment: You don't have $U\cap B = \varnothing$ for _any_ neighbourhood (meaning: all neighbourhoods) $U$. But, and that's all you need, there is some neighbourhood $U_0$ of $x$ with $U_0 \cap B = \varnothing$.

Comment: Ah yes. I forgot to take the negation properly here. Thanks again.

Comment: You have to show that $U\cap A\cap B^c$ is nonempty for an arbitrary neighborhood $U$, but you only show this for **one** neighborhood $U$.

Comment: I think I got it right this time.